# Cannot click on UIButtons after animation in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I am implementing a simple "Gear Menu" animation in a project.

When the user presses the Gear Button, it animates and shows two options ( location and rating ). My problem is that I am able to click on the Gear Button, but cannot click on the Location Button or the Rating Button.

When I click on the Gear Button, the animation starts and the animation should reverse when user clicks on Location or Rating Buttons.

Note: The animation code is generated by a tool called “CoreAnimator”. It is a very famous tool.

I have tried the following things:

1. Set the clipsToBounds property for the superview ( **scaling** ) to “True” to make sure that the Location Button and Rating Button are not going out of bounds.
2. Send the GearView to back in the subviews array of ( **scaling** ).

Still I am not able to click on the Location Button and Rating Button

[Image of the Screen showing Gear Menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qzxWl.png)

Please find my project on dropbox:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/m6nshfzj8h7rux5/AnimTry.zip?dl=0

Comment: you can check whether the button before running the animation is created out of view. If so it is normal to happen because it was built out of the area of action

Comment: Hi Jose, thanks for the reply. I actually checked with CoreAnimator support team and they helped me resolve the problem. Issue was that in CAAnimation only the layer is transitioned, the actual frame of the element remains at its original position in the view. So I had to set the starting position of the elements as the final position and that solved the problem. But thanks a lot for your help